# Getting ClassNotFoundException from Two wars in One ear using Struts 2

Tags: struts2, websphere, classloader, websphere-6.1

I have deployed multiple wars in a single ear to WAS 6.1 with the Web Services Feature Pack installed.  Inside of the ear, there are two wars that use Struts 2.

One of the wars works correctly, as in the application works as expected.

The second application returns the following error:

> [6/27/12 17:20:26:240 EDT] 0000002e WebApp        E   [Servlet
>   Error]-[Filter [struts2]: Could not find required filter class
>   - org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.class]:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.s
>   truts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter

I am aware of the issue highlighted here: http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/multiple-struts-2-wars-in-a-single-ear.html

This exact ear works correclty in the WAS 6.1 Test Enviornment **but not** in the full WAS 6.1 installation.

The class loaders for both WAS installations are defined as MULTIPLE and CHILD_FIRST so both wars get their own classloaders.

1. Question: Is there a difference in the class loaders between
   the WAS test environment and the full production installation?
2. Side Question:  Will I need to create a shared library in the ear to
       resolve this problem?

Comment: I had to create a shared library in the EAR to resolve this issue.